# server error 500 when waiting after clicking

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm testing with Selenium a function for my Django project.

I've got a button to be clicked which redirects to another page, after some processing.

I use to test it:

```
@classmethod
def wait_until(cls, findhow, findwhere):
    WebDriverWait(cls.selenium, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((findhow,findwhere)))
```

So,  I (Selenium) click on the button, which redirect to a page, and on this page, there's a `text_table`. This table is the element that I'm checking to detect the redirection.

```
self.wait_until(By.ID, 'text_table')
```

but I've got immediately (without any pause) a `500 server error`, with the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/backup/BACKUP_Aubrey/workspace/LingL/functional_tests/selenium_text_detail.py", line 56, in test_create_a_new_text
    self.wait_until(By.ID, 'text_table')
  File "/mnt/backup/BACKUP_Aubrey/workspace/LingL/functional_tests/selenium_base.py", line 53, in wait_until
    EC.presence_of_element_located((findhow,findwhere))
  File "/home/campagne/backup_ln/.Envs/LingL/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

(the Message part is empty)

Any idea? 
The browser doesn't seem to take into account the waiting time (10, 20 or 30 seconds...) and redirects immediately. I guess the 505 error is due to the fact that since the redirection is immediate, without allowing the processing which I've coded after the click event (it processes some value sent by GET)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question as you are trying to invoke `click()` so instead of using the expected_conditions as `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use [**`element_to_be_clickable()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

```
@classmethod
def wait_until(cls, findhow, findwhere):
    WebDriverWait(cls.selenium, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((findhow,findwhere)))
```

Moving ahead, you can invoke `click()` method as:

```
self.wait_until(By.ID, 'text_table')
```

Comment: it's not working. By the way, the redirected page contains a `text_table`, but this table is not an clickable element. It still *immediately*  loads the redirected page

Comment: @ThePhi Why are you doing _...So, I click on the button..._ if _...this table is not an clickable element..._?

Comment: I meant: I (Selenium) click on the button, which redirect to a page, and on this page, there's a `text_table`. This table is the element that I'm checking to detect the redirection.